# What happens if a manifested instant gets blinked?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

My [Doom Blade](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Doom%20Blade) is a creature because of [Ethereal Ambush](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Ethereal%20Ambush). If it gets [Turn to Mist](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Turn%20to%20Mist) what happens?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It will lose its face-downness when it gets exiled:

> 400.7. An object that moves from one zone to another becomes a new object with no memory of, or relation to, its previous existence. This rule has the following exceptions.

so it's an instant again. That means it will stay exiled:

> 400.4a If an instant or sorcery card would enter the battlefield, it remains in its previous zone.

> 304.4. Instants can’t enter the battlefield. If an instant would enter the battlefield, it remains in its previous zone instead.